# Various exceptions caused by the Android Fragments compatibility library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have built an app using ([Peter Doyle's](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) slight variant of) the Android support/compatibility library (v4, revision 7) to put together an Activity that uses both Fragments and Google Maps. I have tested the app on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Ice Cream Sandwich), Samsung Galaxy S II (Ice Cream Sandwich), HTC Desire HD (Gingerbread), HTC Wildfire S (Gingerbread) and the emulators. The app runs fine on these devices. No problem. However, I have published the app and am seeing different kinds of error reports caused by this library on various phones, particularly when the Activity is resumed (i.e. it seems the Activity which has the Fragments can't resume itself on some phones without force closing). Below I've pasted some trimmed stack traces to serve as example. Really irritated by this because I can't replicate it on the devices I have. Anyone else experienced similar errors in their development and have any idea what might be bringing them about?

RuntimeException:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   __Unable to start activity...
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   __The specified child already has a parent.
>   __You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1713)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3024)
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   __The specified child already has a parent.
>   __You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
>   ...

IllegalStateException

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   __Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(Unknown Source)
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
>   ...

IllegalStateException

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   __Fragment cw{4067d550} not attached to Activity
>   ...

RuntimeException

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   __Unable to resume activity...
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
>   ...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, did you find out how to avoid those? Seems to be a problem related to the support library and some "custom" android implementation (sony ericson, motorola)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Most, if not all, of my reported errors are caused by this. Not sure if it's the support library specifically or fragments  in general being buggy on some devices. Tried all sorts of things but no joy so just had to live with it. The app ain't going to work perfectly on all devices...

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the v4 library and the only thing that fixed it was to go to properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export and then make sure the v4 box is checked.  Otherwise it was giving me classnotfound errors.  It only started crashing after I moved my file from my computer to dropbox.com back to my computer.  Maybe something changed when you distributed your app?

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas. The support library is compiling ok and even running ok on a lot of devices. However, on some devices only it seems my Activity which has the Fragments can't resume itself properly without getting its pants in a twist and force closing. Curious to know if anyone else has experienced such a problem with the support library and whether there is anything I can do to overcome it.

Comment: Okay, maybe it is a device issue.  You could try to use something like bugsense to get error tracking by device, and maybe figure out its cause. Good luck.